# admob can't find other network adapters - iOS

Tags: ios, admob

This is driving me crazy. I have admob libraries included in my iOS app. I also have the Millennial Media SDK files included.

[image: Admob etc files]

Yet when I run I am getting these errors:

```
flags update: 0X000002
2013-10-15 16:58:52.621 LCApp[21403:a0b] <Google> Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): (
GADMAdapterIAd
). Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target.
2013-10-15 16:58:52.621 LCApp[21403:a0b] <Google> Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): (
GADMAdapterMillennial
). Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target.`
```

I do have `-ObjC` and `-all_load` set in the `Other Linker Flags`

Things are set up correctly in AdMob... how do I get it to find these other adapters???

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nevermind. Being somewhat new to ios development I didn't fully understand that not only did I need the sdk's but also the adapters that are separate downloads (why????)

In case anyone else is so stupid, the adapters are [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/mediation-networks)

Comment: Same problem, same fix. Nice catch! Thanks

Comment: In my case, I just added the required frameworks in documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was missing iAd.Framework. After including this framework, the error stopped showing up.

Comment: Wow that's helped me! Thanks!